# Filling an input field with click on link - not working

Tags: jquery, input, field

I am trying to fill an input field by clicking on a link. The href of this link should determine what will be filled in in  this input field.

```
$(".search_item").click(function(){
    var selectedChamp=$(this).attr('href').split('=')[1];
    $('.textfield').val( selectedChamp );
       return false;
});
```

I used the following JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charlietfl/5u3BZ/
But I just can't get it to work for myself.

The links are generated using JSRender.

On this page: http://lorebook.net/lore/ you can see what I am trying to achieve.
Fill in something in the bar at the top (Just enter the letter "A" it will show some results), the links right there should enter something in the input field.

Strangely enough, at the bottom of this page there are a few links which do actually work. They use the exact same code, but for some reason they work, while the other links don't.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do the links look like? Do they have an `=` in them? If I had to guess I'd say the links that work have an `=` in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
pr = "";
setInterval(function(){
  if(document.location.hash != pr){

    $('.textfield').val( document.location.hash.split('=')[1] );

    // Do what you want

    pr = document.location.hash;
  }
}, 50);
```

Comment: +1 for good workaround ... repeatedly calling the script every 50 miliseconds. but I think it would be more elegant to call it only once after the jautocomplete has generated the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.preventDefault();`
so that on click you trigger the alternative event.

```
$(".search_item").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedChamp=$(this).attr('href').split('=')[1];
    $('.textfield').val( selectedChamp );
});
```

I tested it on your page and it works for me with this little change applied.

**Edit:** I take this back ... as the problem is not the script itself ... and it does the right thing already if I drop it into the console ... which means that at the time the script is initiated it does not find the DOM elements it needs.

- if i initiate the script before searching ... it does not work ...
- if i search and then paste the script into the console ... it finds the `.search_item` elements and works as expected.

**So I am not sure where your above textfield script is currently located ... but you should call it only when the search result elements have been loaded already and can be found in the DOM.**

Comment: Doesn't work. Besides, isn't return false essentially the same?

Comment: hm ... you are right about the return false, but it works for me ... I ta when I run the script into console. The problem is apparently only when you trigger execute the javascript $(".search_item") somehow does not find the DOM elements ... when do you apply the script ... on document load? Maybe you can add a <script> block inside the search results ... to see if it finds them.

Comment: Ah that sounds like a plan. I will report back once I have tried.

Comment: On behalf of [user2162841](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2162841/user2162841): They suggest `.on('click',...` vs `.click(...`.